# How to add CSRF token to HTTP header Angular

Tags: angular, csrf, csrf-token

currently i am using below functions in my project. now i need to modify my code to add CSRF token. can you help me to do it.

```
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  getAuthorizationHeader(): HttpHeaders {
    return new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('JWT_TOKEN'))
      .set('user', localStorage.getItem('username'))
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
     
  }

}
```

This is my sample request.

```
  getPendingList(): Observable<any> {              
    return this.http.get(url.getVerifyExpList + `${localStorage.getItem('traceId')}`,  {headers : this.apiService.getAuthorizationHeader()});
  }
```

how i add CSRF to my code. thanks

Implement CSRF token validation in Angular